# SqLite Delete command with subquery

Tags: sqlite, subquery, sql-delete

I have following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM pojmovi WHERE pojam LIKE '%og'
) WHERE pojam NOT LIKE '%olog';
```

This works as expected, selecting all from column `pojmovi` that ends in 'og' but not in 'olog', now, I want to delete those results, so I'm trying something like:

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT * FROM pojmovi WHERE pojam LIKE '%og'
) WHERE pojam NOT LIKE '%olog';
```

And this query causes **near "(": syntax error**
Is this somehow possible in sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

This can't possibly work as you want - you attempt to delete from an intermediate query result and that makes no sense and is not allowed. You need to specify an actual table after `DELETE FROM`. Something like this:

```
 DELETE FROM pojmovi WHERE ( pojam LIKE '%og' ) AND (pojam NOT LIKE '%olog' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time.

After little experimenting, I came up with this query that works as expected, as far as I can tell:

    `DELETE FROM pojmovi WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id FROM (
         SELECT * FROM pojmovi WHERE pojam LIKE '%og'
        ) WHERE pojam NOT LIKE '%olog'
    )`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM pojmovi WHERE pojam LIKE '%og' and pojam NOT LIKE '%olog';
```

and

```
DELETE FROM pojmovi WHERE pojam LIKE '%og' and pojam NOT LIKE '%olog';
```

Your queries will be slow because they cannot use an index (because you are doing LIKE "%...")